# How to correctly store JWT Refresh Tokens in a database?

Tags: authentication, flask, jwt

I have been using Flask and JWT to create authentication on my backend. Creating and using access tokens is simple enough, but I've run into some conceptual misunderstanding when trying to discover how to handle the usage and storage of refresh tokens.

Upon initial login, I distribute an access token (with 10 minute expiry) and a refresh token (with 4 day expiry). The 'jti' attribute of the refresh token is stored in a table on the database, along with its expiry date. The access token is stored in memory, and the refresh token is stored in HttpOnly cookies. When the access token expires, a "silent refresh" is sent to the backend with the refresh token. It is first checked for validity (user ID matches up, signed correctly, and is not expired), and then the database is checked to see if it contains that specific refresh token's 'jti'. If it does, then that refresh token is deleted from the database (and can therefore no longer be used) and a new access token and refresh token are sent to the user. This allows for the refresh tokens to only be single use. However, if a user logs out and logs back in repetitively, the refresh token cookie in their browser keeps getting overwritten with a new value (which is fine), but the database now contains a ton of references to "unused" refresh tokens. I'm not sure if my understanding of the JWT workflow is completely incorrect, or if this is normal.

I mainly conceptually followed [this guide](https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/). Is this repetitive logging in and getting refresh tokens normal? I don't see how to manually find and remove older (but still valid) tokens that are used in the same browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation looks fine. It's normal that you issue new tokens for a new session. I think there are two solutions to your problem:

1. Add a `expiration` column to your table with refresh tokens. Then you will be able to remove stale `jti`s from the table once they're expired.
2. Instead of keeping information about issued refresh tokens, you can keep information about used refreshed tokens. So, when you issue the token you don't save it in the DB. When the user uses the RT, you can save the `jti` and `expiration` in the DB. Whenever a RT is used you check whether the `jti` is in the DB. If it is, you decline the request. You can remove entries from this table after expiration, as you verify expiration on the RT anyway.

Comment: Why storing the expiration in the database if you can add the expiration timestamp into the token itself?

Comment: The expiration is probably in the token anyway, but the one in the token is of no use to what the author needs. The expiration in the database is used to clear stale data not to verify the validity of the token. You need that information in the database in order to clear data. The expiration kept in the token won't be of much use to you if you never receive that token.

Comment: Well, Imho creating a script which just decodes the JWT and check for expired would be enough to clean the expired ones, saving a column in the database.

Comment: Many databases have features for automatically clearing stale data, but you need a timestamp column on which the feature can make its decision. I think that having an additional column and using database features to clear data will perform much better than running any script.

Answer (score 1):

I was worried, as you are, when implementing an Access/Refresh flow with overwritting refresh tokens (there are other strategies,as keeping a blacklist and a whitelist).

I discovered that there were two ways to end with "unused" refresh tokens (as you say) or, as I prefer to name them, "stalled" refresh token (you will see why in a second):

**First way: LogOut**

As you detected Log Out can lead to stalled refreshed tokens in the database.
Probably, you, as me, (and 90% reading this answer) were just "logging out" from the Client side, aka "deleting Access and Refresh tokens" from the client memory/cookies/localstorage and done. Right? Why so?

However, you can send a "/logout" request to your server with your access token (to authenticate) and your refresh token (in the body), so you can delete the refresh token from the database. I would not pass the JTI, but the whole refresh token (after all it is going to be erased shortly afterwards, so no issues if anyone intercepts it with a MIM attack). This way you can double check the user requesting the /logout is exactly the owner of the refresh token (as a security measure), this security check would be lost if you send just the JTI value (which could lead to an attack: an user requesting a refresh token to be erased, through its JTI, from other user). (Yes you can use the JTI to perform a database check to know its owner, but each time the server performs a database call "God kills a kitten", while you can easily compare the user_id in the access against the user_id in refresh token)

Performing a /logout call, each time the user "/logout" you are really killing her refresh token from the database. And hence the ability to create access tokens if the refresh token got compromised (or sniffed) before the user performed a /logout. If an attacker got the "unused" refresh token, even if the user logged out, could exchange it for a refresh and access token again. Let's reduce the "number of refresh tokens" able to create access tokens for an user.

**Second Way: Expired Tokens**

A second way to have a "stalled" token is when the client tries to /refresh but the refresh token is already expired. In such case, dont just return an error code that will be used by your app to send the user to the Log In page, but also delete the refresh token from the database. Why do you need to keep it? This cleanup strategy reduces the size of your table and helps to clean your database of already expired refresh tokens. You, ofc, will need a script to clean refresh tokens from users "never-returning" to your app or from users who decided to delete localstorage/cookies, but ey! your cleanup script will be fast as hell now.

This second way is the reason I prefer to call all of them "stalled" because they are sitting there (ones being "unused", others being "expired") and filling your table.

Hope these strategies help your security concerns, a pleasure to meet someone as "geek" as me regarding JWT security.